# Pass select into where_in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to select ids and pass it into update by using this

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a.sponsor_id) as sponstr FROM (select sponsor_id from sponsor  WHERE (pay_success = 'yes')AND (end_date_time > NOW()) and ((country_id = 1 and state_id = 24) or city_id = 123)
order by rand() limit 0,10) a");

    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
     foreach($query->result() as $sponsorids)
     {

        $data['se_count'] = 0;
        $this->db->where_in('sponsor_id',$sponsorids->sponstr);
        $this->db->update('sponsor',$data);

     }
     }
```

but all the ids does not update, only the first one does.

the where_in produces the code below

```
 WHERE sponsor_id IN ('5,4,2,3,1')
```

which i think it should be

```
  WHERE sponsor_id IN (5,4,2,3,1)
```

Am I missing anything here or am I doing anything wrong which obviously I know I am. Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass an array there. So pass not `$sponsorids->sponstr` but `explode(',', $sponsorids->sponstr)`

Also it's seems like a bad DB design decision, take some time and have a look on many-to-many concept